# Format text based on a 4-digit number

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a received a word doc with one paragraph of jumbled text and I'm trying to figure out what is the fastest way to format it to the way I want. This is what file currently looks like:

```
9000Lost and Found9001Injured/Sick Person9002Workplace Accident9003Dangerous Conditions9004Disturbance
```

For every 4-digit 9000 number, there is a word description. This list goes on until it reaches to the code 9990. This is the format that I would like the text to appear in:

```
9000 Lost and Found, 9001 Injured/Sick Person, 9002 Workplace Accidents, 9003 Dangerous Conditions, 9004 Disturbance
```

The format can remain as 1 giant paragraph. I just need to split the 4-digit code and text descriptions.

I've tried using Find and Replace, but it ends up inserting commas wherever it sees a '9'. Is there some way that I can split up the text in the corrected format? I'm using Word 2010.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would do that with notepadd++. Search and replace (Reg-ex):
search:
(\d+)
replace:
, \1 
with a space at the end.

Comment: Word has a drop down section of wild cards and special characters that you can include in search/replace.  One is "Found Text".  So search for 9 and replace with "comma space <found text>".  I spelled them out for clarity, but you'll type the actual characters for comma and space.

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl-H to open "Find and Replace" window.

Then, enable wildcards, and do this replacement:

- Find what: `[0-9]{4}`
- Replace with `^&` and space after it

[image]

More info about using wildcards in Word (generally they are known as regular expressions) could be found here:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-and-other-data-in-a-Word-document-c6728c16-469e-43cd-afe4-7708c6c779b7?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US