# Searching and replacing numbers

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, find-and-replace

I use a lot of charts in documents and need to re-number them sequentially.  I can use the following to find the next occurrence of a number within text:

```vb
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "^#"
```

However this selects only the first digit.  If I use this to replace 1 with 5, it works fine, but if the number being replaced is  10, then I end up replacing it with 50.   How do I make sure that I am selecting the whole number before I replace it?

Comment: Try `"^#{1,4}"`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is regex to find any number:

```
<[0-9]{1,}
```

I have tested on this text:

```
5

50

500

5000 500 5000 20 5 00000000000
```

Obviously, wildcards must be enabled.

[image]

Comment: See also related question with my answer: https://superuser.com/questions/1270496/format-text-based-on-a-4-digit-number